# AR Image Tracking: Unable to create NFT feature and image sets with Carnaux's Node.js app

Tags: node.js, web-applications, augmented-reality, artoolkit, ar.js

I am trying to generate the featured set and image set of an image for use as an NFT Marker in an ar.js webapp using [Carnaux's NFT Marker Creator](https://ar-js-org.github.io/NFT-Marker-Creator/)

Every time I try to generate an NFT set from an image the application seems to function as normal, generating features for 76 to 0.736 DPI images, before spitting out the following error:

```
emscripten_realloc_buffer: Attempted to grow heap from 536870912 bytes to 1073741824 bytes, but got error: RangeError: WebAssembly.Memory.grow(): Unable to grow instance memory.
```

I've run the process with 3GBs of ram with the flag --max-old-space-size=3000, but am unable to allocate it any more memory as --max-old-space-size 4096 throws the error:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[6216:0460C490]       37 ms: Mark-sweep 1.0 (3.0) -> 0.7 (3.3) MB, 1.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.912, current mu = 0.912) allocation f
ailure GC in old space requested
[6216:0460C490]       61 ms: Mark-sweep 1.2 (3.3) -> 1.0 (3.3) MB, 2.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.913, current mu = 0.914) allocation f
ailure GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

Does anybody have any idea what the error is here and how I might resolve it? I'm absolutely up to using alternate tools but I haven't found any other NFT Marker generators.

Comment: IMO you should open an issue on https://github.com/Carnaux/NFT-Marker-Creator/issues addding more useful informations, with which device you are building the NFT marker? Are you using the node or web version? some information of the image (size, dpi...)

Comment: @Kalwalt Woah, hi Kalwalt! I completely forgot to open an issue on the NMC GitHub page you're right, thank you for the reminder. 

Shortly after I posted this question I read [your very helpful guide on training ARToolKit natural feature tracking](https://kalwalt.github.io/artoolkit-docs/3_Marker_Training/marker_nft_training.html), and have started using [genTexData](https://kalwalt.github.io/artoolkit-docs/3_Marker_Training/marker_nft_utilities.html) instead. 

Thanks for all the work you guys do at the AR.js org! It's great stuff :D

Comment: Hi, @Tadgh  thank you! yes you can also build the NFT marker with genTexData, there are no differences, i added a comment in the issue, i hope we can find the reason of that issue.